# Enable debugging on HTC Desire

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, air, android

I am building a flex app for mobile. I am running my app with configuration 'run on device' but when I connect to my device through usb I don't see my application launching.Can somebody help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran through the same problem some time back. you can find the steps to enable it on my blog.
[Debugging on htc desire](http://hellomadhur.blog.com/2011/05/09/enable-debugging-on-htc-desire-mobile-with-flex/)